# Why won't `let` work for naming internal recursive procedures?

Tags: lambda, scheme, factorial, let

Consider the following implementation of a function to compute factorial: [1]

```
(define fac-tail
  (lambda (n)
    (define fac-tail-helper
      (lambda (n ac)
        (if (= 0 n)
            ac
            (fac-tail-helper (- n 1) (* n ac)))))
    (fac-tail-helper n 1)))
```

I attempted to rewrite using `let` for the inner define:

```
(define fac-tail-2
  (lambda (n)
    (let ((fac-tail-helper-2
            (lambda (n ac)
              (if (= 0 n)
                  ac
                  (fac-tail-helper-2 (- n 1) (* n ac))))))
    (fac-tail-helper-2 n 1))))
```

There is no error at `define` time, but execution results in:

```
#;> (fac-tail-2 4)
Error: undefined variable 'fac-tail-helper-2'.
{warning: printing of stack trace not supported}
```

How can I make the `let` version work?

Scheme version is SISC v 1.16.6

**[1]** Based on the iterative version of `factorial` in section 1.2.1 of SICP http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-11.html#%_sec_1.2.1

Comment: it's good to know there are people hacking with scheme out there... :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How can I make the let version work?

Use `letrec` instead of `let`.

Comment: The essential difference is that the body of a letrec'd procedure can refer to itself while the body of a let'd procedure cannot.

Answer (score 6):

R. Kent Dvbvig says:

---

In fact, a `let` expression is a syntactic
extension defined in terms of lambda and procedure application, which
are both core syntactic forms. In general, any expression of the form

```
(let ((var expr) ...) body1 body2 ...)
```

is equivalent to the following.

```
((lambda (var ...) body1 body2 ...)
 expr ...)" [1]
```

---

Which means that `fac-tail-2` is equivalent to:

```
(define fac-tail-2
  (lambda (n)
    ((lambda (fac-tail-helper-2)
       (fac-tail-helper-2 n 1)) ;; <== scope where fac-tail-helper-2 is visible.
     (lambda (n ac) ;; this lambda is assigned to fac-tail-helper-2
       (if (= 0 n)
           ac
           (fac-tail-helper-2 (- n 1) (* n ac))))))) ;; <=== problem
```

And it becomes clear that the problem is that the `fac-tail-helper-2` name visible as a
paramenter in the body of the `lambda` highlighted above, but is not a name
within the `lambda` that is assigned to parameter `fac-tail-helper-2`.

[1] Section 2.5, "Lambda Expressions" of *The Scheme Programming Language, 4th Edition* http://scheme.com/tspl4/start.html#SECTGSLAMBDA

Answer (score 0):

**Two other alternatives, being added for completeness.**

*The Scheme Programming Language, 4th Edition* Section 3.2 has two other alternatives for using `let` and recursive functions. http://scheme.com/tspl4/further.html#./further:h2

The first is clever and not recommended. It involves adding a parameter to the lambda that is a lambda that it calls, and then passing itself in to get everthing started.

```
(define fac-tail-4
  (lambda (n)
    (let ((fac-tail-helper
            (lambda (fac-tail-helper n ac)
              (if (= 0 n)
                  ac
                  (fac-tail-helper fac-tail-helper (- n 1) (* n ac))))))
      (fac-tail-helper fac-tail-helper n 1))))
```

And simpler is the named `let` which could be used insead of `letrec` for single recursion.

```
(define fac-tail-3
  (lambda (x)
    (let fac-tail-helper ((n x) (ac 1))
      (if (= 0 n)
          ac
          (fac-tail-helper (- n 1) (* n ac))))))
```

Though that version hides an implicit lambda definition that is being tied to fac-tail-helper.