# Scheme function to return a function that calculates a zero value

Tags: scheme, lisp, higher-order-functions

I'm currently writing my first Scheme programs and I'm now trying to program the following function:

The function should take another function as an argument and should return a function with one argument that calculates a zero value of of the given function for a given x.

The algorithm im trying express is: `Xn+1 = Xn - f(Xn) / f'(Xn)` The function should iterate until `X - Xn < 0.0001`.
I already wrote the function that calculates `f'(x)` (`diff`).

My current code looks like this:

```
(define (make-nf f)
  (lambda (x)
    (let ((fn (diff f 0.1))
    ((innerfunc x xn)
      (if (< (- x xn) 0.0001)
          xn
          (innerfunc (- x (/ (f x) (fn x))))
          ))))
    (innerfunc 0 x)))
```

My actual problem is the iteration part. I don't know how to make the returned function iterate or call itself or an inner function. As you can see above, I tried to define a named inner function that gets called until the defined precision is reached. I'm also aware that the start of the ieration with `0 x` would be wrong.

Comment: Are you trying to define `innerfunc` as a function that takes two arguments `x` and `xn`?

Comment: Right, because I need to compare the old `X` and the new `Xn`.

Comment: These questions may be relevant: [Defining a function inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15250514/what-is-the-difference-between-defining-a-function-inline-or-not/15250702#15250702) and [Why won't `let` work for defining internal recursive procedures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169444/why-wont-let-work-for-naming-internal-recursive-procedures)

Comment: Thanks this helped me fixing my syntax errors!